# Making text in a linked div selectable

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am creating a web page and have a section that I want to be linked, inside this section though I have some text that I want to allow the user to copy and paste from (i.e they need to be able to highlight it). Because the text is inside the linked div though I am unable to select it, how can I make the text selectable?

Here is the code I have...

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <div class="container"> 
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p class="selectable-text">Text that can be highlighted here</p>
        <p>Other Text</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

I've tried putting this in the CSS, but this just changed the cursor, it didn't actually make the text selectable...

```
.selectable-text{
    cursor:text;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a-Elements don't allow block-elements inside of them. So you cannot structure your layout that way. What about only making the heading a link? That would be fine and you could easily select the other text:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <h2><a href="http://example.com">Heading</a></h2>
    <p>Text that can be highlighted here</p>
    <p>Other Text</p>
</div>
```

In order to make the whole container clickable, you can apply a Javascript Event Listener to all containers. If you are already using jQuery, this can be done very easily:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    });
}).addClass('link');
```

The difference from this to a "real" link is that it won't be draggable and instead selectable. Anyway you can click on it and it will locate you to where you want to go. It will also apply a class `.link` which you can use in your stylesheet in order to set a pointer as the cursor.

For people who have javascript disabled there will still be a link in the heading, so your page stays usable in every case.

Comment: I was going to do this, but the container class has a quite a big background and so I want to allow the user to click on any of the background and still get to the desired location.

Comment: But you have still an illegal structure in your original posting, because you must not have block elements inside of a link. I updated my answer now, so that you can fulfill your approach with a javascript.

Comment: Would it be legal if I just replaced <div> with <a> and applied all the CSS styles that were applied to <div>, to <a>?

Comment: In HTML5 this would be allowed, see the last part: *The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).* (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-a-element.html#the-a-element) but this will not solve your original problem. ;)