# Link tag <a> able to select text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the text that appears in the status bar of Chrome. Since it's not possible to use status.text anymore (for security reasons) I am wrapping an `<a>` tag over `<body>` so my code is `<a href="text that I manipulate" onclick="return false;"><body>...</body></a>` .

It's working as expected cause every time the user moves the mouse inside the page the status bar shows exactly what is inside the href attr of `<a>`. The problem: I did not realize till now that I cannot select any text inside the page cause if it's treated as link. I am using return false onclick event of  and it works great cause the user is never redirected however it's not possile to select text inside the `<a>`.

Is there a CSS property that allows me to change that behaviour? It only occurs if `<a>` tag.

Comment: <a ..><body>...</body></a> is not valid html

Comment: This is the biggest `a` I have ever seen, whole body..

Comment: You might want to check out the `title` attribute

Comment: use a footer with a placeholder div that you can update instead; that works on non-mouse devices as well.

Comment: Status bar of Chrome, and not only Chrome, is better to let be as is. I don't see why to change it.

Comment: @Huangism it's not valid but works. But can anyone explain why is not possible to select a word inside a <a> ?

Comment: Wow, what a hack! I think you need to think of ways to achieve your result without using <a> around the body, but not looking for ways to hack the hack. First I would like to know why you would want to manipulate the status bar? The status bar is not meant to be artificially manipulated, so I would suggest if you want to display preliminary descriptions about the page, use the title attribute on body so it display a popup on hover.

Comment: @Martijn the title attribute does not work http://jsfiddle.net/ADATb/

Comment: @Samul what's the point of it working in the front end when your entire document is invalid. If someone really wants to find out what the link is, there are many ways to do so and you cannot stop them

Comment: @Huangism no the title attribute does not manipulate the status bar, but it displays a popup containing the descriptive text regarding the element. Depending on the OP's need this may be a more suitable effect than artificially manipulating the status bar. What do you think?

Comment: @Martijn I get the feeling OP is trying to hide the normal text that comes up when you hover a link in the status bar

Comment: Similar question was asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414071/making-text-in-a-linked-div-selectable, in short, not possible what you want to achive.

Comment: @EmilBorconi I know it's not possible but my hack DID WORK. I can manipulate the status bar and my solution is unique. I read hundreds of links about this and my idea is unique and it works. But I have no idea why is it not possible to select a word inside <a> tag like <a>XX YYY ZZZ AAA</a> WHY cant I select the word YYY? When I click trying to select the browser does nothing and does not allow me to select the text.

Comment: my comment was about selecting the word inside the a tag that is not possible. see what I have linked.

Comment: @EmilBorconi You are right, it's not possible to select a text inside <a> tag. Is there any other clue I can use to achive the result of changing the status?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the CSS property `pointer-events`.

`a{pointer-events:none}` would disable the *mouse event* for that element.

But a better approach would be to add the URL in data-attribute and on click event you can navigate to those URL with **location.href**.

```
<a href="#" data-url="www.x.com"></a>
```

Will that help?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of hacking. This is invalid markup and bad code, but as a proof of concept (at least for Chrome).

One could use various combinations of mouse events, range selection and editable. Tricky part is to calculate what and where to select.

Sample code should give you selection of the first words in a paragraph; as in: click on the start of each paragraph like somewhere in *"Lorem ipsum"* or *"Duis posuere"* to select some of the words. This could then be combined with `mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mosueup` etc. to select *correct text*.

[Chrome only Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/Qm2r9/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just for fun, and this is not the real hack but it something close:

Do like this:

```
<body>
<div class=container>bla bla bla</div>
<a href="my custom text" id=the_hack></a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".container").hover(function(e){
$("#the_hack").trigger("focus");
});
</script>
```

Of course it will have some limitations, when you select text the status bar will disappear, also if you highlight text move the mouse out of the div than back in, the selection will be lost, but hey it's a hack.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eF7Gc/) what I mean.